# listwidget PyQt5 как привязать файл к элементу в списке

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, обработка-сигналов, qlistwidget

Я хочу чтобы при запуске программы в поле `listwidget` выводились все допустим **.txt** файлы, которые есть в директории.

По сути мне нужно чтобы элемент списка был привязан к файлу, например **`n.txt`** и при срабатывании функции, которая считывает нажатия по элементам открывался **`n.txt`**.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как привязать элемент списка к файлу и как в функции сделать так чтобы при нажатии на элемент допустим `item1` открывался **`n.txt`**, а на `item2` **`o.txt`**.

У меня в мыслях, что такое возможно сделать через `for`.

код на pastebin https://pastebin.com/8NM1HziZ

Весь код:

```
import os
import sys
from pygame import mixer
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 402)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.182, y1:0.102409, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.113636 rgba(0, 62, 79, 147), stop:0.306818 rgba(28, 14, 68, 156));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-130, -40, 1031, 491))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("2HYI.gif"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 641, 80))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget) #Начиная отсюда list
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 121, 311))
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font: 75 italic 8pt \"MS Sans Serif\";\n"
"color: rgb(121, 92, 121);")
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roman")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
     
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item")) #Элементы, пришло в голову что можно воспользоваться такой структурой
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)                     #Но я всё равно не знаю как привязать элемент к файлу и как сделать открытие файла.
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.itemlist = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', ] #список из элементов
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.itemlist)
        
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
    def onClicked(self, item): #При нажатии на элемент срабатывает функция и выводит "0" 
        print('0')
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Часть с элементами.

```
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item")) #Элементы, пришло в голову что можно воспользоваться такой структурой
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)                     #Но я всё равно не знаю как привязать элемент к файлу и как сделать открытие файла.
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.itemlist = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', ] #список из элементов
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.itemlist)
        
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
    def onClicked(self, item): #При нажатии на элемент срабатывает функция и выводит "0" 
        print('0')
```

Отвечать на то, как получить список файлов в директории не обязательно, мне важна лишь возможность привязки элементов к файлам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам реализация того, что вам рассказал @SergeyTatarincev, а также другие полезные вещи.

```
import os
import sys
# ?from pygame import mixer
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("""
        #centralwidget, QListWidget { 
            background-color: qlineargradient(\
                spread: pad, x1:0.182, y1:0.102409, x2:1, y2:1, \
                stop:0.113636 rgba(0, 62, 79, 147), \
                stop:0.306818 rgba(28, 14, 68, 156));
        }
        """)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-130, -40, 1031, 491))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap("opencv_color.jpg").scaled(1031, 520))        # !!! 
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 641, 150))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #035397 ;")        # +
        
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 121, 311))
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font: 75 italic 12pt \"MS Sans Serif\";\n"
"color: rgb(121, 192, 221);")
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roman")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
     
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item")) 
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)                     
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


class VLine(QFrame):                                              # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super(VLine, self).__init__()
        self.setFrameShape(self.VLine|self.Sunken)
        
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.listWidget.clear()                                     # !!!
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #035397; color: #FFAA4C; font-size: 15px;")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        
        btn_dir = QPushButton('Выберите папку')
        btn_dir.clicked.connect(self.update_dir)
        
        self.statusBar().showMessage("bla-bla bla")
        self.statusBar().reformat()
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet('''
        QStatusBar {
            border: 0; 
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #FFAA4C;
        }
        QStatusBar::item {border: none;}
        ''')
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(btn_dir)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())
        _date = QDate().currentDate()      
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(QLabel(f"Data :{_date.toString('dd.MM.yyyy')}"))
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())
        
    def onClicked(self, item): 
        path_file = item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        with open(path_file, 'r') as file:
            self.textEdit.setText(file.read())
        
    def update_dir(self): 
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self,
            "QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()",
            '.'
        )
        if directory:
            _list = [ file for file in os.listdir(f"{directory}") if file.endswith(".txt") ] #/*.txt")]
            if not _list:
                return
            self.listWidget.clear()
            for i, item in enumerate(_list):
                self.listWidget.addItem(item)
                item_data = os.path.join(directory, item).replace('\\', '/')
                self.listWidget.item(i).setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, item_data)            
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как сделать то же с mp3...? (функция должна открывать mp3) просто что бы определялось что это именно тот mp3 (как с txt) мне важно знать лишь как просто открывать например проигрыватель windows, проигрывание в проге сам смогу сделать.

Comment: @DaYa это уже другой вопрос. Примите решение по данному вопросу и задайте новый вопрос. Приложите пример кода и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0):

К каждому элементу вы можете привязать собственные данные любого типа (QVariant). Используйте для этого setData с ролью Qt.UserRole.

```
self.listWidget.addItem("my new item");
self.listWidget.item(0).setData(Qt.UserRole, "my data")
```

Для того чтобы получить ассоциированные с элементом данные, используйте соответственно data(Qt.UserRole)

```
def onClicked(self, item): 
    print(item.data(Qt.UserRole));
```

Comment: Можно более подробный пример? Так же я не знаю привычка это или нет но мне нужно чистое использование Python(Для чего ;)